# vector functions in c++ (rookie)

Tags: c++, vector

So I'm trying to a basic program to check chess moves in c++ and I need to write a function that does vector addition(linear algebra style) with two vectors (c++ style) as parameters and returning a vector (c++ style).

So I wrote:

```
std::vector<int> vecadd(std::vector<int> a, std::vector<int> b) {           
    if (a.size() == b.size()) {
        std::vector<int> p(a.size);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size; i++) p[i] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size; i++) p[i] = (a[i] + b[i]);
        return p;
    }
}
```

and my code doesn't compile.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The error message.

Comment: try p.push_back(a[i] + b[i])

Comment: Your function should return a vector in all branches and throw an exception if it fails to do so.

Comment: If `a.size()` != `b.size()`, what should `vedadd` return?

Comment: and missing return - if they are different sizes what are you going to do? Maybe you want std::array instead of std::vector

Comment: I actually figured it out.  Also, I didn't know what to do for error checking.  Thanks.

Comment: Post error log/more details

Comment: You don't really want do copy a and b, do you?

Answer (score 1):

You need `size()`, not `size`. It's a function. In C++, when you call a function, you need to use parentheses even if the function takes no arguments.

With that being said, you have a serious issue in your code. When the vectors are not of equal size, you don't return anything. That's undefined behavior. In this case, your function returns random garbage.

You need a way to indicate to the caller that an error occurred. For example you can throw an exception:

```
#include <exception>
// ...

std::vector<int> vecadd(std::vector<int> a, std::vector<int> b) {
    if (a.size() != b.size()) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Vector sizes were not equal.");
    }
    std::vector<int> p(a.size());
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) p[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) p[i] = (a[i] + b[i]);
    return p;
}
```

(There's still issues in the code, but that's off-topic for this answer; see the comments for further things that can improved.)

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured that out as you were putting this in.  Also, thanks for help with the error checking.  I wasn't exactly sure how to do that.

Comment: @AdamGluntz There's some other small issues with your code, but it's off-topic for the answer. For example, you don't need to clear `p` with zeros (first for loop), since you're assigning to every element of it anyway (in the second for loop.) Furthermore, you don't actually even need `p`. You can just store the results in `a` instead and return `a` at the end: `a[i] = a[i] + b[i]`.

Comment: Just to double check, that won't change the value of the parameter outside the function, right?  I don't want my vector addition function to accidentally move the rook some place it shouldn't go.

Comment: @AdamGluntz `a` is taken by value, not by reference, so it's a copy of what was passed to the function. Modifying it has no effect on the original vector. Generally, it's a good idea to avoid copies, so in fact it would actually be better to take both `a` and `b` by `const` reference, and reintroduce `p` to store the results. In that case, the `vecadd()` function signature would need to be: `std::vector<int> vecadd(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b)`. Now, no copies are made. But of course you now need `b` to hold the result. Which is still faster.

Comment: @AdamGluntz Here's the "correct" code: https://pastebin.com/yKtfnyJS Note that `p` is not constructed with an initial size. That's more expensive since it initializes every element. Instead, `p` is empty at the beginning and then we reserve memory for it without initializing anything, by using the `reserve()` function. That means we then need to use `push_back()` to add the elements into the vector since it's empty.

Comment: @NikosC. There's an argument for taking a by value and b by const reference, which turns the loop body into `a[i] += b[i]`

Comment: @Caleth That still copies `a`. In the end, I think it's best to have `p` to hold the result and take both `a` and `b` by reference. No copies are made anywhere that way. (See previous comment.)

Comment: @NikosC. Yes, but copying a is about the same as instantiating p, unless you can move into a, where it is better

Comment: @Caleth Instantiating `p` only allocates memory. Copying `a` instantiates the new local `a` which allocates memory, **and** copies the data from the original `a` to the local `a` :)

Comment: @NikosC. yes, but you still have to read the data out of `a`, through the +, to put into `p`

Comment: @Caleth You do that anyway. When taking `a` by value, you'd read the data twice. Once for the copy, once for the addition operation. With `p`, you only do it once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150709/discussion-between-caleth-and-nikos-c).

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with the code you are writing, at one point you do

```
if (a.size() == b.size())
```

using `x.size()` 
because is a function what you are calling, then why you are doing later `p(a.size);`???

you need to do :

```
std::vector<int> p(a.size());
```

instead of `std::vector<int> p(a.size);`

and of course the same applies to the loops

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) p[i] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that uses [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) and [`std::plus<int>`](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) to achieve the same result:

```
std::vector<int> vecadd(std::vector<int> const& a, std::vector<int> const& b)
{
    if (a.size() != b.size()) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Vector sizes were not equal.");
    }

    std::vector<int> result;
    result.reserve(a.size());

    std::transform(a.begin(),
                   a.end(),
                   b.begin(),
                   std::back_inserter(result),
                   std::plus<int>());

    return result;
}
```

Note that I changed your function signature. The two vectors are passed to the function by const ref and not by value to avoid copies and express the fact that the function doesn't modify the two vectors inside of it.

Comment: You either need to resize the result vector (or use the original constructor) or use `std::back_inserter` for the result parameter.  Having said that, std::transform isn't the solution to the proposed problem.

Comment: @stefaanv Thanks, I edited my answer by adding an std::back_inserter. If the question was "I need to write a function that does vector addition [...] with two vectors [...] as parameters and returning a vector [...]", I think this answers the question.